# python venv setup ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sqlalchemy' despite verifying it is available in virtual environment

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, setuptools, python-venv

Okay, I'm at a bit of a loss here. I'm fairly new to Python and wanted to do a simple REST-app with Flask and SQLAlchemy.

Obviously I have missed some step, but I cannot see it, can someone please have a look and see what I'm missing?

These are the steps I have done so far:

1. Create a folder for my project
2. Create a setup.py inside my project folder with the following content

   from setuptools import setup

   ```
   setup(
     name='pyrecipe',
     version='0.0.1',
     packages=['pyrecipe'],
     include_package_data=True,
     install_requires=[
       'click',
       'flask',
       'sqlalchemy',
       'flask-sqlalchemy',
       'gunicorn',
       'itsdangerous',
       'jinja2',
       'markupsafe',
       'werkzeug',
     ],
   )
   ```
3. Creating a venv with `python -m venv venv` and activating it with `source venv/bin/active`
4. Installing packages with `pip install -e .`
5. Setting up the flask env with `export FLASK_APP=pyrecipe && export FLASK_ENV=dev`
6. Running the app with `flask run`
   I get the following output

> Error: While importing "pyrecipe", an ImportError was raised:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 235, in locate_app
>
> ```
> __import__(module_name)
> ```
>
> File "/home/cvelin/code/python/pyrecipe/pyrecipe/**init**.py", line 4, in
>
> ```
> from pyrecipe.database import init_db
> ```
>
> File "/home/cvelin/code/python/pyrecipe/pyrecipe/database.py", line 1, in
>
> ```
> from sqlalchemy import create_engine
> ```
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sqlalchemy'

**init**.py content

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

from pyrecipe.database import init_db

init_db()

import pyrecipe.views
```

database.py content

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

engine = create_engine('postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost/postgres', convert_unicode=True)
db_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False,
                                         autoflush=False,
                                         bind=engine))
Base = declarative_base()
Base.query = db_session.query_property()

def init_db():
    # import all modules here that might define models so that
    # they will be registered properly on the metadata.  Otherwise
    # you will have to import them first before calling init_db()
    import pyrecipe.models
    Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
```

Running `pip list` shows that the modules all got installed:

> Package          Version Location
>
> ---
>
> click            6.7
> Flask            1.0.2
> Flask-SQLAlchemy 2.3.2
> gunicorn         19.9.0
> itsdangerous     0.24
> Jinja2           2.10
> MarkupSafe       1.0
> pip              18.0
> pyrecipe         0.0.1   /home/cvelin/code/python/pyrecipe
> setuptools       39.0.1
> SQLAlchemy       1.2.10
> Werkzeug         0.14.1

and using the python interactive interpreter works as expected

> >>> from sqlalchemy import create_engine
>
> >>>

Comment: Did you install flask with virtualenv too? Looks like flask is being loaded from `/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/cli.py` not `/home/$user/.virtualenvs/$your_virtual_env/packages/` so maybe it can't find the packages in the virtual env because it's not in the virtual env itself? You could try making the env from scratch using `virtualenv --no-site-packages target-directory` to ensure no packages are used from the system installation of python

Comment: Yes I did, I used the `venv` module instead of using the `virtualenv` command, but even if I delete the virtual environment and add `--clear` and `--no-site-packages` and running with `virtualenv` it still gives me the same result.

Comment: Also, confirming with `which`, the python binary and the pip binary used are the ones from the bin folder in my virtual environment.

Comment: Actually, I'm letting this go, it seems to be related to the flask dev server or my setup. The project actually runs fine using gunicorn and I will stick with that.

Comment: The actual solution was to deactivate and then source the activate script once again after installing the required packages. Using `which flask` confirmed that it was trying to use the global binaries, instead of the virtual environment binaries.